# Is there any possibility of messages loss in RabbitMQ cluster, when that I have durable queues and messages delivery mode is persistence?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I had an production incident and after resolution of incident we found some of the messages were lost. I have a cluster of three instances. There was some network problem between then that is why I restarted all three nodes simultaneously. Letter on the issue was resolved but some messages were lost.

queues configurations-

- all queues are durable.
- messages delivery mode is persistence.

I tried few few thing but I didn't get any messages loss. such as -

- I restarted RabbitMQ server on all the instances simultaneously on dev environment.
- I rebooted all the instances but there was no loss of messages.

Is there any other possibility of messages loss in such scenario?

Comment: You need to ensure your publishers are using publisher confirms correctly. Then, read [this article](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/10/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-rabbitmq-cluster).